# Is it ever necessary to invoke default ctor in constructor initialization list?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

For example, if I have the following:

```
class Foo;  // has default ctor

class Bar {
 public:
  Bar(Foo* f);
}

class MyClass {
 public:
  MyClass();

 private:
  Foo foo_;
  Bar bar_;
}

MyClass::MyClass() : foo_(), bar_(&foo) {}
```

This more or less compiles without warnings, see https://godbolt.org/g/yx464A [slightly modified so Foo is fleshed out].

It also compiles fine without foo_() in the initializer list. But is there ever a case where one would need to invoke the default ctor?

Comment: No, not really. If you omit it, `foo_` will still be constructed using its default constructor. I can't think of any situation where removing `foo_()` would change the semantics (assuming `Foo` is really a class, and not, say, a `typedef` for `int`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: But `Foo` can be a class but contains `int`, and so there might be have difference: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b736121f5cd3ba97).

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, right. There's a difference if `Foo` is an aggregate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `foo_` will be default-initialised:

> `[C++11: 12.6.2/8]:` **In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member** or base class **is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id*** (including the case where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no *ctor-initializer*) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> - if the entity is a non-static data member that has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, the entity is initialized as specified in 8.5;
> - otherwise, if the entity is a variant member (9.5), no initialization is performed;
> - otherwise, **the entity is default-initialized** (8.5).

Whether that's what you wanted is up to you. For a POD, default-initialisation (which won't do anything to POD members) may not be enough. For a class with an actual default constructor with non-POD members to initialise, the initialisation will cascade as you'd expect.